# Adicionar imagens no mongodb via api usando o postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

Bom dia, 
Estou construindo uma api em nodejs para acessar o mongodb. Eu quero adicionar imagens nesse banco e retornar o caminho dessa imagem para a minha aplicação android. Quero armazenar as imagens diretamente no banco ou usando o postman. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu faço para adicionar as imagens no mongodb?

Aqui está o código atual.

```
medicoRouter.post('/medicos', (req, res, next)=>{


    async function salvaMedico(){
        const medicos = new Medicos({
            nome: req.body.nome,
            formacao: req.body.formacao,
            crm: req.body.crm,
            cidade: req.body.cidade,
            //caminho_foto: url_imagem,
            //data_atualizacao: null
            });


        try{
            const result = await medicos.save();
            console.log("Operação realizada com sucesso");
            res.status(201).send({ message: "Cadastrado com sucesso!"});
            /* res.statusCode = 201;
            res.send(); */
        } catch(erro){
            console.log(erro.message);
            res.status(406).send({ message: "Cadastro falhou"});
            /* res.statusCode = 406;
            res.send(); */
        }
    }

    salvaMedico();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que você vai precisar usar uma dependência chamada "multer" para trabalhar com envio de multipart/form-data. Para instalar, basta:

```bsh
npm install --save multer
```

O multer adiciona um objeto `body` e um objeto `file` ao objeto `request`.
Ou seja, você pode acessar o `req.body` e o `req.file` no seu código.

Da [documentação do multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), um uso básico seria:

```js
var express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }) //caminho que o arquivo ira percorrer

var app = express();

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file é o arquivo avatar que vem do form <input type="file" name="avatar" />
  // req.body os campos de texto se houver algum
})
```

No seu caso, uma forma de armazenar o caminho do arquivo no mongodb pode ser feito da seguinte maneira:

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({
      dest: 'seu/caminho/para/upload',
      storage: multer.diskStorage({ //aqui irá gerenciar o armazenamento no disco
         destination: (req, file, cb) => {
             cb(null, './seu/caminho/para/salvar');
         }
      });
});

medicoRouter.post('/medicos', upload.single('nomeCampoForm'), (req, res, next)=>{ 
//fazendo upload de um único arquivo de cada vez usando o método single()

    async function salvaMedico(){
        const medicos = new Medicos({
            nome: req.body.nome,
            formacao: req.body.formacao,
            crm: req.body.crm,
            cidade: req.body.cidade,
            caminho_foto: req.file.path, //alteração aqui 
            //data_atualizacao: null
            });

            //req.file.path irá buscar dentro do objeto file, o caminho especificado
       [...]
    salvaMedico();
});
```

Creio que isso irá resolver a princípio seu problema.
Aconselho a ler mais sobre a [documentação do multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), é bem intuitivo e tem muito mais coisas que podem te ajudar na hora de lidar com upload de arquivos. Por exemplo, definir os tipos de arquivo que o upload aceita (Mime types).

Não esqueça de adicionar `enctype="multipart/form-data"` no seu formulário ou definir isso no postman.

Espero ter ajudado.